# Wordpress custom folder as homepage

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

In my wordpress I have a folder name `custom` which is a custom script. I visit myexample.com/custom the script does work. But I wish to use `myexample.com` for the script instead of `myexample.com/custom`. I want to replace the custom script rather than displaying the default homepage of wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Just add template comments in top of you main file under the custom folder.

```
<?php /* Template Name: Example Template */ ?>
```

How to create page template: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/

Create a new page select this page template from page template dropdown and set this page as home page.

Comment: inside my `custom`, it has few files, it's a script, not a template

Comment: What do you mean by script, isn't it PHP script?